# Eclipse 4.2 release perspective issue

Tags: eclipse, user-interface

I've downloaded latest Eclipse platform 4.2.1 and faced issue with configuring views for different perspectives.

I'm unable to configure views independently for different perspectives, after configuring some perspective and switching to another I can see my changes were applied to all perspectives. This is undesirable for me. Is there a way to use old "independent" style of perspectives configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably running into is a new "feature" in Eclipse 4.2 (Juno), namely the ability to drag views out of the Perspective. This new "area" for views shows up regardless of what Perspective, so what you're seeing is that you've put views there and now they show up in all Perspectives, making it seem like all Perspectives have been changed.

They (the Eclipse Platform UI team) are working on some improvements to the drag-and-drop of views that will, supposedly, make it harder to do this and thus less confusing to users.
See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367920 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349867

Comment: what should I do NOT to drag view out of Perspective and experience old good functionality?

Comment: Be very careful :-)
Seriously, read the bug report I linked to; I think they describe what it loos like when dragging a view will place it in the "outside the Perspective" area.

Comment: I see now. The point is in different rectangle position in case view should be within current perspective or out of it. Thank you.